# Rails helper method refactor

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I have this messy helper method:

```
def gesture(klass, item, text, desc)
  element_class = klass.to_s + " gesture"
  content_tag :li do
    if klass == :sell  
      link_to new_reply_path(item_id: item.id), title: desc, data: {qtip: desc}, class: element_class do
        content_tag(:div, nil, class: element_class) +
        content_tag(:span, text, class: 'gesture-text')
      end
    elsif klass == :alternative
      link_to new_reply_path(item_id: item.id, alternative: true), title: desc, data: {qtip: desc}, class: element_class do
        content_tag(:div, nil, class: element_class) +
        content_tag(:span, text, class: 'gesture-text')
      end
    elsif klass == :join
      link_to new_item_affiliation_path(item), title: desc, data: {qtip: desc}, class: element_class do
        content_tag(:div, nil, class: element_class) +
        content_tag(:span, text, class: 'gesture-text')
      end
    end  
  end 
end
```

As you can see, it has a lot of repetition, any idea on how I can refactor it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd write:

```
def gesture(klass, item, text, desc)
  element_class = [klass.to_s, "gesture"]
  url = case klass
  when :sell
    new_reply_path(item_id: item.id)
  when :alternative
    new_reply_path(item_id: item.id, alternative: true)
  when :join
    new_item_affiliation_path(item)
  else
    fail("Unsupported klass: #{klass}")
  end

  content_tag(:li) do
    link_to(url, title: desc, data: {qtip: desc}, class: element_class) do
      content_tag(:div, nil, class: element_class) +
        content_tag(:span, text, class: 'gesture-text')
    end    
  end 
end
```